# Two pgfplots with axes side-by-side are not aligned correctly

Tags: pgfplots, horizontal-alignment

I'm trying to place two pgfplots with a very simple axis beside another one. For some reason, the plot spans too far and no matter how I try to scale or limit the size of the axis it is always too wide.

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=-5.0, xmax=5.0,
    ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5,
]
\addplot[mark=none,draw=red,ultra thick]{tanh(\x)};
\end{axis}%
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{flushleft}%
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushright}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=-5.0, xmax=5.0,
    ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5
]
\addplot[mark=none,draw=red,ultra thick]{tanh(\x)};
\end{axis}%
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{flushright}%
\end{minipage}%
\end{figure}
```

[image]

I've read countless posts that sounds the same as mine, but none of them have my exact problem, and I've "fixed" the common problems that solved some of the other ones.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Nowhere in your code you change the size of the plots. Add e.g. `width=0.4\textwidth` to the `axis` options to do so. Then you will be able to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thank you @StefanPinnow . Sorry about stupid question. It was my understanding that the plots would take up 100% of the "parent" element width by default, and be scaled thereafter, but I explicitly have to set the plot widths? If this is the case then it all makes sense. The plots have not, as far as I've observed, been scaled no matter what I've said the minipages should be.

Comment: Correct. The `width` is by default `240pt` so scaling the `minipage` won't do anything ...

Comment: I've tested it now and setting the width option does indeed scale the plot, however, the width you specified made the plot way too small, but it looks ok with the option `width=1\textwidth`. Can I be certain that this option does take up the entire width of the minipage, or how can this be specified? Btw, if you post this as an answer I'll accept it right away.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already stated in the comments below the question the default width of the `axis` is `240pt` and thus scaling the `minipage` doesn't change the width of the plots.

And because of that, just providing e.g. `width=0.55\textwidth` to both `axis` environments is sufficient and the `minipage` environments aren't needed at all.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \noindent\hrulefill

    \noindent
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            width=0.55\textwidth,
            xmin=-5.0, xmax=5.0,
            ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5,
        ]
            \addplot[mark=none,draw=red,ultra thick] {tanh(\x)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
        \hfil
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            width=0.55\textwidth,
            xmin=-5.0, xmax=5.0,
            ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5
        ]
            \addplot[mark=none,draw=red,ultra thick] {tanh(\x)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the zoomed result of above code]